# How can I get Online meet List 'Meet Now' - Microsoft graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I want to get Online meeting list.

I tried
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/eadf9340-f10b-4ea9-aaea-1ec45bc645dc/events
It returns online meeting list, But It not return 'Meet Now' List.

I also Read this api
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

But I don't now how to get 'VideoTeleconferenceId'.

How can I get Online meet list 'Meet Now' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API to get a list of all the onlineMeetings.

It is the responsibility of the calling application to store the ID of a online meeting at the time that onlineMeeting is created.

the VideoTeleconferenceId is for use by VTC applications that have their own VTC ID, and specify this when creating a new OnlineMeeting, and then can retrieve the meeting using that same VTC-ID

I suggest you check [Events with an OnlineMeeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-4-create-and-enable-an-event-as-an-online-meeting), as they can be listed.